# How to using if statement in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i want to minus 1 (-1) value from `durasi_pre_u` if `durasi_pre_u` have basic value bigger then 0 and update `Premium` to `Member` when `durasi_pre_u` have value = 0.

here what i try

```
UPDATE user 
SET durasi_pre_u = IF(durasi_pre_u > 0, durasi_pre_u - 1, durasi_pre_u), 
pangkat_u = IF(durasi_pre_u <> 1 AND pangkat_u = 'Premium', pangkat_u = 'Member', pangkat_u)
```

this code working -1 `durasi_pre_u` but not working change `Premium` to `Member`

i try to follow tutorial from this site https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/control-flow-functions/if-function.php

Comment: Do you want to update the table or just select the transformed data `durasi_pre_u`?

Comment: im edit my question

Comment: Should `pangkat_u` get updated after `durasi_pre_u` or before updating `durasi_pre_u`

Comment: i think after `durasi_pre_u`

Comment: What I meant was, should `pangkat_u` get updated based on the updated value of `durasi_pre_u`?

Comment: You need to replace `pangkat_u = 'Member'` with `'Member'` and change the `<>` to `=`

Comment: @Nick i got error if i remote `'`

Comment: That was a mistake, I edited my comment after you saw it...

Comment: @Arihant yes, it will update to `Member` when `durasi_pre_u` = `1`

Comment: @Nick thanks nick, write u answer, so i can approve it...

Comment: @Jazuly answer posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your query, firstly you only want to change the value of `pangkat_u` when the current value of `durasi_pre_u` is 1 (so it is about to change to 0) so you need to change the `<>` to `=`. Secondly you have `pangkat_u = 'Member'` as the new value, which is treated as a boolean expression (i.e. a value of 1 or 0) by MySQL. What you actually want is just `'Member'`. So your query should be:

```
UPDATE user 
SET durasi_pre_u = IF(durasi_pre_u > 0, durasi_pre_u - 1, durasi_pre_u), 
pangkat_u = IF(durasi_pre_u = 1 AND pangkat_u = 'Premium', 'Member', pangkat_u)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `If` function, you only need to specify the values to be set in case of true or false. Dont specify the field name = value (`pangkat_u = 'Member'`)

Use the following :

```
UPDATE user 
SET durasi_pre_u = IF(durasi_pre_u > 0, durasi_pre_u - 1, durasi_pre_u), 
pangkat_u = IF(durasi_pre_u <> 1 AND pangkat_u = 'Premium', 'Member', pangkat_u)
```